# Np.Argwhere To Produce Numbers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working on price weighted indexes for a class and although it is a very simple calculation by hand I figured it would be good practice for my novice python skills.

**Edit**
So this is the code that I am working with now

```
StockBPrice = np.array([35.1, 45.6, 41.5, 47.8])
StockCPrice = np.array([52, 67.6, 61.5, 67.7])
StockDPrice = np.array([89.5, 107.4, 53.7, 64.4])

QuantityB = np.array([300,300,300,300])
QuantityC = np.array([400,400,400,400])
QuantityD = np.array([100,100,200,200])

PriceArray = []
for i in range(0,1):
    if np.argwhere(StockBPrice) < 2:
      PriceArray.append((StockBPrice+StockCPrice+StockDPrice)/3)
    else:
      d = (StockBPrice[2]+StockCPrice[2]+StockDPrice[2])/((StockBPrice[1]+StockCPrice[1]+StockDPrice[1])/float(3.0))
      PriceArray.append((StockBPrice+StockCPrice+StockDPrice)/d)

PriceArray = np.array(PriceArray)
print PriceArray
```

I want to use the indices as a condition but `np.argwhere` gives a boolean but it is the general idea that I want to use.

Comment: Could explain a bit of the math behind your desired result? What exactly are you trying to calculate? What is the purpose of the loop?

Comment: `len(StockBPrice < 2)` will always be the length of the array, with a numpy array.  You can test this by doing just `StockBPrice < 2` and looking at the output

Answer (score 1):

Very easy

```
if len(StockBPrice) < 2:
```

Comment: well I feel like the biggest dingus in the world.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the condition when the length is equal to 2 is not handled. If you have this conditional statement

```
if len(StockBPrice) < 2:
```

Then the other condition should be

```
if len(StockBPrice) >= 2:
```

However, it is better to play around the code using if else. So it is better to format your code like this:

```
if len(StockBPrice) < 2:
    do something
else:
    do something else
```